# Generating code based on .json and .gotmpl file

Tags: go, freeipa, texttemplate

I am asking this simple question as, after researching for quite some time, I still haven't found an answer yet.

I am trying to use this repository https://github.com/StefanAbl/go-freeipa, and updating the generated code with the latest freeipa version I use (which is 4.10 with API 2.280). In the "developping.md"  instructions, they talk about a `gen` tool to generate the freeipa code.

The code is using `.json` files and a `.gotmpl` file to generate the code (from what I could grasp).

I have NO idea what they are talking about. I have absolutely never coded in Go (but can fix things here and there due to the language ease of use) so I am not familiar with weel-known packages. I tried to find help online, especially with this tool https://github.com/clipperhouse/gen or the `go generate`, but it doesn't seems right. The `clipperhouse/gen` expects `+gen` tags in the code (which doesnt exists in the repo) and `go generate` does work with tags as well.

Note that I also tried to do a `go run main.go` but I receive those errors:

```golang
# command-line-arguments
gen/main.go:53:21: undefined: Schema
gen/main.go:58:13: undefined: SchemaDump
gen/main.go:64:18: undefined: Command
gen/main.go:96:21: undefined: Class
gen/main.go:190:20: undefined: ErrDesc
gen/main.go:195:12: undefined: ErrDesc
gen/main.go:202:27: undefined: Schema
gen/main.go:202:42: undefined: ErrDesc
gen/main.go:204:16: undefined: toGoType
gen/main.go:215:11: undefined: Schema
gen/main.go:215:11: too many errors
```

After checking the code, indeed those (types?) are not declared which explains the errors. And I am not versed in the language enough to be able to fix this myself :( Or even if it needs fixing due to the fact that I should use this `gen` tool instead.

**If anyone has an idea on How I should generate the freeeipa/generated.go file, based on the files in freeipa/gen, that would be awesome :)**

PS : For your curiosity on why I am doing this:

I am trying to update the go-freeipa package with the latest `freeipa version`. The Freeipa-issuer https://github.com/guilhem/freeipa-issuer I am trying to setup on my K8S cluster is returning a
`Failed to sign certificate request: Fail to request certificate: json: cannot unmarshal string into Go struct field CertRequestResult.result.value of type int` error> I hope this error comes from the fact that `go-freeipa` client is using an `oudated freeipa version` (4.9, api 2.170 instead of 4.10 and api 2.280) to generate the code.

Answer (score 2):

Actually I am stupid :)

Diving a bit more into the code and comapring it the go documentation, I realised that doing `go run main.go` only runs the `main.go` file, ignoring other files in the package.

I naively thought they were imported and therefore used when calling the `main.go` file.

A simple `fix`  (which is not a fix but just correctly starting the program)  is to do a `go run .`  instead of `go run main.go` :)